# importing data from excel to access using ms access forms

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access-2010

I have one excel file which contains data,I have to import the data in excel file using the ms access form UI.I need to create form which takes input as excel file and inserts the records in the MS access table. I need to place some logic using VB before inserting the data to MS access.

Kindly guide me how I can achieve it as I am naive in this technology.

Comment: If you are using MS Access forms in MS Access, do you mean VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MS Access external data wizards to link the Excel file and then proceed as if the linked table was native to MS Access.

You can also use in VBA [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to link or import Excel.